# Angular $routeProvider to handle different URLs differently

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In angular, is there a method to load different views & controllers when the routes are basically the same, but the actual string in the route is different?

In terms of routing, if the top level route parameter is being already used, is there way to load different View & Controller based on the different route parameter?

Below is what I was trying:

```js
app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when("/", {
        templateUrl: "app/components/0_home/homeView.html",
        controller: "HomeController"
      }) // Home
      .when("/about", {
        templateUrl: "app/components/1_about/aboutView.html",
        controller: "AboutController"
      }) // About
      /*(...Bunch of other .whens)*/

    //Project
    .when("/project/:projectId", {
        templateUrl: "app/components_project/0_home/homeView.html",
        controller: "ProjectHomeController"
      })
      .when("/project/:projectId/HOME", {
        templateUrl: "app/components_project/0_home/homeView.html",
        controller: "ProjectHomeController"
      })
      .when("/project/:projectId/FLOORPLAN", {
        templateUrl: "app/components_project/1_floorplans/floorplanView.html",
        controller: "FloorplanController"
      }) // Floorplan
    .when("/404", {
        templateUrl: "app/components/404.html"
      }) // else 404
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/404'
      });
  }
]);
```

I wanted to load

> app/components_project/0_home/homeView.html

when routeProvider is

> /project/:projectId/HOME

and load

> app/components_project/1_floorplans/floorplanView.html

when routeProvider is

> /project/:projectId/FLOORPLAN

Or is there any better way to handle this kind of situation?

Comment: Actually, when you test "/project/:projectId/FLOORPLAN" it goes on "/project/:projectId" ?

Comment: It goes to 404 because /project/:projectId/HOME is getting used.

Comment: For example: http://localhost:8081/WEBSITE_NAME/#/project/266/HOME works, but http://localhost:8081/WEBSITE_NAME/#/project/266/FLOORPLAN goes to 404...

Comment: can change template using `templateUrl:function($params)` but hard to assign controller dynamically. Might want to upgrade to ui-router

Comment: I've tested on my computer, after having reproduced your project structure, using the same routes as you and it worked correctly, so you have not an error in your route configuration

Comment: Thank you, I've looked it again this morning and found out it was actually a different issue than my route config...

Comment: Ok, maybe you can answer your question so ? It could be useful for someone